# Using .find() and .each() in JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a PHP file which is a view (so mainly HTML) composed of several tables.
When the user click on one of the `button`, I want that the variables that are into my cells (and into the correct table) are sent to a Table in my Database.

To do this i'll use AJAX later, but at the moment i've a problem using JS/Jquery.

So I did something like this :

```
$('.boutton').click(function(){

    $(?).find('td input').each(function(){
        console.log($(this));
        console.log($(this).val());

        var iValue = $(this).val();
        var sAllId = $(this).attr('id');
        var sName  = $(this).attr('name')
    });

});
```

My table and buttons are into a div which has as `id` "table" + the number of the table.

I don't know what to do since I want this to work on every table, and on every button. It has to select only the td input that is into the table where the button was clicked.

My HTML is into a variable $sHtml since everything in this table are made of datas (in my DB) but it should be something like this :

```
  <table id = "domaine-1-south">
    <tr>
      <th>BlaBla</th>  // Several times
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blabla</td>
      <td><input id = "1#1#1#" name="high"></td>
      <td><input id = "1#1#1#" name="mid"></td>
      <td><input id = "1#1#1#" name="low"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Blabla</td>
      <td><input id = "1#1#2#" name="high"></td>
      <td><input id = "1#1#2#" name="mid"></td>
      <td><input id = "1#1#2#" name="low"></td>
    </tr>
```

For the id 1#1#1# the last 1 is for the number of the line and the second one is for in which table I'm.

Comment: Are table and button siblings? Showing the HTML will surely help to provide a more accurate solution

Comment: Add your HTML code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use "start with" selector `^=` to select all tables that have an `id` start with `table` :

```
$('[id^="table"]').find('td input').each(function(){
```

But in your OP you want to select the specific `table` related with the clicked button `.boutton`, so i guess that you have this `button` inside the table so you could select the current `table` using :

```
$(this).closest('table[id^="table"]').find('td input').each(function(){
```

Hope this helps.